# Inequality with primes, logarithms, and a finite set.

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime ($n \geq 1$) and put $d_n = p_n - p_{n-1}$ for $n>1$ and $d_1 = 2$. Let $N\{S\}$ denote the number of elements in a finite set $S$. Show that for every $c>0$, $$N \left \{ n: p_n \leq x , d_n > c \log x \right \} \cdot c \log x < \sum_{p_n \leq x \\ d_n > c \log x} d_n \leq x$$
>   to deduce that for suitable $c,$
>   $$N \left \{ n: p_n \leq x , d_n > c \log x \right \} >> \pi (x).$$

I am not clear on how to show any of these statements. My idea for the last statement (not sure if it is the right approach) is to show
$$N \left \{ n: p_n \leq x , d_n > c \log p_n \right \} < N \left \{ n: \sqrt{x} < p_n<x , d_n > c \log p_n \right \} + O(\sqrt{x}) < \frac{2x}{c\log x} + O(\sqrt{x}),$$ which I'm also having difficulty with. Any ideas on how to proceed/conclude?

Clarification:

$f(x) << g(x)$ if $\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} < M$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

$f(x) = O(g(x))$ if $\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} < M$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Not as hard as it looks. For instance, a hint for the first statement. We can rewrite $N\{n: p_{n} \leq x, d_{n} > c \log x \} = \sum_{p_{n} \leq x, d_{n} > c \log x} 1$. Thus, $d_{n} > c \log x$ gives us...

Comment: @Mr.SnowRemover Does it give $$\sum_{p_n \leq x \\ d_n > c \log x} 1 < \sum_{p_n \leq x \\ d_n > c \log x} 1\cdot c \log x < \sum_{p_n \leq x \\ d_n > c \log x} d_n < \sum_{p_n \leq x \\ d_n > c \log x} p_n \leq x?$$

Comment: Check the given expression: N{...} * $c \log x$. That means you don't need your first inequality. Besides, note that d1 + d2 = p2 - p1 + p3 - p2 = p3 - p1; they cancel one another while summing themselves